# js trigger click on a based on children element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger the click on `a` tag which has div with `id='a'`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])").click();
  //$("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])").trigger("click");
  $('#chat_list_content a').click(function() {
    alert('you are here');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat_list_content">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="a">A</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="b">B</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Click should happen automatically and output alert box. But, there is no respond from the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain clearly/

Comment: @vadivela,   I want the click happen automatically without user action. The trigger on a should be based on div id inside a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `$("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])").click()`, the custom click handler is not yet described yet.  That means it doesn't do anything. You just need to move the click trigger below the click function definition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])").trigger("click");
    $("#chat_list_content a").click(function() {
      alert("you are here");
    });

    // Make sure to add this after the click handler definition above
    $("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])").click();
});
```

working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-gagarin-t55er

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `:has()` here at all, you can simply use [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to achieve what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#chat_list_content a').click(function(){
    alert('you are here at '+ $(this).index());
  });
  $('#chat_list_content a div[id=a]').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat_list_content">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="a">A</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="b">B</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Premlatha, there is a clear difference between the selector `$('#chat_list_content a div[id=a]')` and `$("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])")`

Comment: I am using `$("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])")` because i want to trigger click on `a`. So, i search for a that has div with id='a'. But, `$('#chat_list_content a div[id=a]')` also work since div is inside a. Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: @Premlatha, that is what `$('#chat_list_content a div[id=a]')` does in the answer above, please notice the index in the *alert*...

Comment: Output same index,0 as `$("#chat_list_content a:has(div[id='a'])")`.

Comment: @Premlatha, what I am trying to say is both the selectors are doing the same thing, but `$('#chat_list_content a div[id=a]')` is more faster and clean:)